# Как правильно согласовать предложение

Tags: общие-вопросы, согласование, глаголы, род, местоимения

Как правильно написать?
1) *"Как прошел ваш 9-ое мая"* (май-месяц муж.р)
2) *"Как прошло ваше 9-ое мая"*

Answer (score 1):

> Как прошл**о** у вас 9 мая? (Если это не о формальном мероприятии: "Как вы
>   провели 9 мая?")

Согласование по грамм. роду с подразумеваемым словом "число" [девятое (число) мая].  "Ваше девятое мая" - не очень хороший стиль; это может быть воспринято как пренебрежительное высказывание (ср. "эта ваша заливная рыба"). Но похожее выражение "ваш выходной" вполне нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: "Как прошло ваше 9-е мая".

Наращение "-ое" излишнее, но коли вы употребляете девят*ое* в среднем роде , то и **ваше**. А по-другому, не "девятое", тут и не скажешь, традиционная форма, хотя не уверен, что наверняка от "числа".

Мужской род здесь может возникнуть не от мая, а от опущенного "праздник", например, но так не принято. Если праздник "опущен", то уже средний род.

Стилистически - да, тут можно править, но нужно ли - это уже вам решать.